# Quick create a class in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm fairly new to programming and I've always used Visual Studio. But I've recently switched to VS Code because it is faster and works better with Windows Subsystem for Linux. However there are several features from Visual Studio that I can't find on VS code. The biggest one is the ability to create a class that automatically creates the .cpp file and .h file with the basic code structure already in there. Is there a way to do this on VS Code? If not is there an extension for this? Sorry if this question has already been asked. I'm still not great at finding answers to my questions online (I've heard finding answers on stackoverflow is one of the most important skills to gain as a programmer).

Comment: create 2 snippets, for cpp and h file, and set placeholders for the name

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it takes very long to just create them manually with just a class name, especially in vs code, but this extension looks like it might do something like what you're looking for.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ACharLuk.easy-cpp-projects